# Error [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, openxava

Quiero conectar OpenXava con Microsoft SQL Server, sin embargo, al habilitar esa opcion en el context y el persistence me da error. Al correr el programa si me da la direccion a la pagina y si puedo escribir informacion sin embargo, al momento de clickear el boton de "grabar" me aparece el error: "**Ha sido imposible ejecutar la acción Grabar: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory**" Saben como solucionarlo?
Tambien habilite la opcion del TCP IP de la configuracion de SQL server. Y cree la base de datos y el usuario con su login.
Asi esta mi codigo:

persistence.xml

```
<properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="123"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=facturaciondb;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
```

context.xml

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/facturacionDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          maxTotal="20" maxIdle="5" maxWaitMillis="10000"
          username="user" password="123" 
          driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
```

pom.xml

```
      <!-- Microsoft SQL Server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>12.4.1.jre11</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: No es necesario incluir los detalles de conexión en persistence.xml dado que ya se encuentran en context.xml. persistence.xml debería tener el nombre JNDI del origen de datos. Consulta la documentación para ver un ejemplo. Además, necesitamos ver la traza para saber la causa del error.

Comment: @javierpaniza podría revisarlo por favor, se lo agradecería muchísimo. Saludos. https://github.com/solee2222/CLINIC.git

Comment: Para revisarlo debería ver la traza de la excepción, que deberías incluir en la descripción del problema